# Correct usage of the word 'though'

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, commas

I've come across multiple answers on this forum about the correct usage of the word 'though'. Despite all this, I am still not confident about my following sentence. Is 'though' correctly used? -- separated with a comma from its preceding clause. Is it good usage of the word in that context?

> Clearly, this is in contrast with the Big Bang Theory, though it is conceivable that the total energy of the Universe is zero.

Comment: Assuming it makes sense in the context (hard to say without knowing what “this” is—or indeed without knowing a lot more about Big Bang Theory and the universe than I do), your use of _though_ is perfectly logical, natural, and idiomatic here. You could use _although_ as well.

Comment: 'Though' here is the [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/though_1) concessive / mitigating sense: << _though conjunction_ (2) used to add a fact or an opinion that makes the previous statement less strong or less important [or to add a contrasting concessionary caveat]:
'They're very different, though they did seem to get on well when they met.'
'He'll probably say no, though it's worth asking.' >>